# Java Stream from List of List to Set

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<List<String>>` how do I use Java 8 stream to iterate and store this into a Set?

I am trying something along this line but i couldn't quite make it compile

```
List <List<String>> itemLists = ...
    Set <String> codes = itemLists.stream()
    .flatMap(itemList - > {
        items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    });
```

Comment: hi I use only String classes in my example

Comment: You need to apply `collect` after `flatMap`, not inside it

Comment: `seatMap.getItem().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: sorry i have simplified my example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
Set<String> lst = itemLists.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 6):

Use just one time from `flatMap()`

```
itemLists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```